# laptop antenna for HP Notebook

Tags: wireless-networking

We are currently hooked up to local cable company for phone, internet and tv. Moving to a new home that does not have that available. Will an antenna for a laptop work when there is no cable or satellite to hook to? We can get internet on our cell phones, so am wondering if an exterior antenna for our laptops will work the same way as for our cell phones

Answer (score 1):

You can always share your phone's internet connection with your PC either through enabling a WiFi hotspot or through USB tethering.

[Here is a good article explaining how you can do that.](http://www.howtogeek.com/213329/how-to-share-your-smartphones-internet-connection-hotspots-and-tethering-explained/)

USB tethering is the fastest and easiest option available. It displays your phone as a network device for your computer which can then be used to access the Internet. Here is how to share internet through USB tethering:

**iPhone:**

USB tethering will happen automatically if you have iTunes installed on your machine. Just plug and play.

**Android**

"Connect your phone to your laptop via a USB cable and you'll see the USB tethering option become available. Enable it and you'll see a new network adapter in Windows. The USB tethering connection is described as a “Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device".

Comment: Just in case that link dies, you may want to post some of the more important bits from it in your answer. That way if the link dies or the host page goes down, the information is still available here!

Answer (score 1):

You can of course buy a connector for your Laptop, but you will need a data contract (similar to a smart phone), which costs significantly.

Sharing your phone's connection is an option, but the allowance might be quickly depleted, depending on your contract and usage.

Generally, using 3G or LTE for connecting is easy and works well, but is neither a cheap nor a fast connection.